# I need an Arabic keyboard on iPhone without installing anything?

Tags: iphone

There are already inbuilt fonts for Arabic

I need to use Arabic keyboard - without installing any software.

I don't want internal - keyboard.

That is => if I change my setting to iPhone =>keyboard arab & english on.

In textField I will have option to switch on both language.

What I require is => my own keyboard for my application.

That is. If I tap on textField (for english input) internal english keyboard should be pop up.

And if I tap on other textField (for arabic input) my keyboard (or any other option suggested by you) should be pop up.

Comment: ok ! now how to set iphone's settings programatically.
That is -> my Application should set->ON arebic lang.Keyboard if it is not.

Comment: @sagar, if you edit that comment into your original question, you might be able to prevent this from being closed.  I was about to click close until I read that.

Comment: or
If i tap on textField(for arebic input) => only arebic keyboard should be pop up.(no english keyboard) => no chance for english input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Settings -> General -> Keyboards -> International Keyboards -> Arabic [ On ]

Comment: Is it possible programmatically ?

Answer (score 2):

Settings > General > Keyboard > International Keyboards